# Split numeric vector by NoData

Tags: r

I have a numeric vector with some NoData values. How could I split it in vectors using the NoData as break points?

Example data:

```
set.seed(1)    
a <- as.integer(runif(30, 0, 10))
a[1] <- NaN
a[10] <- NaN

    > a
 [1] NaN   3   5   9   2   8   9   6   6 NaN   2   1   6   3   7   4   7   9   3   7   9   2   6   1   2   3   0   3   8   3
```

So the output would group the data by continuous vectors:

```
[1] 3 5 9 2 8 9 6 6

[1] 2 1 6 3 7 4 7 9 3 7 9 2 6 1 2 3 0 3 8 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `split`

```
split(a, cumsum(is.na(a)))
```

However, the first element of every list can be `NA` which can be removed with `sapply`

```
sapply(split(a, cumsum(is.na(a))), function(x) x[!is.na(x)])
```

Answer (score 1):

An option with `rleid`

```
libary(data.table)
grp <- rleid(is.nan(a))
split(a[!is.nan(a)], grp[!is.nan(a)])
#$`2`
#[1] 3 5 9 2 8 9 6 6

$`4`
#[1] 2 1 6 3 7 4 7 9 3 7 9 2 6 1 2 3 0 3 8 3
```